# Vuetify dropdown looks different than in documentation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am using Vuetify template (form in a dialog) and copying the exact same code to my local vue.js projects but they are producing different results

The code is the exact replica from the official Vuetify website.

```
<template>
      <v-row justify="center">
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent width="1024">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-btn color="primary" v-bind="props"> Open Dialog </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="text-h5">User Profile</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field label="Legal first name*" required></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Legal middle name"
                      hint="example of helper text only on focus"
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Legal last name*"
                      hint="example of persistent helper text"
                      persistent-hint
                      required
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field label="Email*" required></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Password*"
                      type="password"
                      required
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                    <v-select
                      :items="['0-17', '18-29', '30-54', '54+']"
                      label="Age*"
                      required
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                    <v-autocomplete
                      :items="['Skiing', 'Ice hockey', 'Soccer', 'Basketball', 'Hockey', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Coding', 'Basejump']"
                      label="Interests"
                      multiple
                    ></v-autocomplete>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
              <small>*indicates required field</small>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="dialog = false">
                Close
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="dialog = false">
                Save
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-row>
    </template>
    <script>
      export default {
        data: () => ({
          dialog: false,
        }),
      }
    </script>
```

I am using the template above which shows the following result:

[image]

However in my local vue.js file it show as follows:
[image]

I don't quite understand the issue here.
My main.js file which I followed the documentation of the Vuetify to add it existing project:

```
import {
    createApp
} from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import OpenLayersMap from "vue3-openlayers";
import "vue3-openlayers/dist/vue3-openlayers.css";


import 'vuetify/styles'
import {
    createVuetify
} from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
})




const app = createApp(App);
//app.use(OpenLayersMap);

createApp(App).use(router).use(vuetify).use(OpenLayersMap).mount("#app");
```

Comment: You are missing the [icon font](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/)